# Django+uwsgi: uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248]

Tags: uwsgi

I have this weird issue in my django application. I am using the admin interface. When I try to load the change page it doesn't render completely and when i see in logs it says:

**uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 248]

IOError: write error**

The page has been working fine before and suddenly this started happening. And also the behavior is inconsistent. If I reload the page multiple times, few times it renders correctly. This issue is happening in production environment and I am not able to replicate it on my local. The production server is using uwsgi 1.9.10 with nginx and django 1.5. Also I am writing custom HTML on page and there is an inline table also on the same page.

Please let me know if anyone knows why it is happening...

Answer (score 6):

that error means the client (browser) disconnected before getting the full response. Check your webserver logs, maybe you hit a timeout